# Why does User.Identity not contain the whole list of ClaimsTypes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, claims

I am working on an ASP.NET Core web application. My dotnet version is 3.1.401 and I am with Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.2. I am using cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity. Everything works well.

In the footer of my `_Layout` view, I display the name of the authenticated user which I can easily access with `@User.Identity.Name`. But I would like to add his role too. I first thought it would be possible using this `@User.Identity.Role` but it is not.

Here is the list of claims created after successful login:

```
Admin loggedAdmin = form.LoginCheck();

if (loggedAdmin != null)
{
    if (!loggedAdmin.Deleted || !loggedAdmin.IsActive)
    {
        string name = StringCustomMethods.GetInitialsFromFirstName(loggedAdmin.FName) + loggedAdmin.LName;

        var userClaims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, loggedAdmin.Role),
            new Claim("Id", loggedAdmin.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim("RoleType", loggedAdmin.Role),  <---- created to access it easily
        };

        // Passes list of claims and AuthenticationTypes
        var claimsListAndAuthTypes = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, "User Identity");

// etc...
```

I then created a new Claim in the list with a string type to be able to use this: `@Context.User.FindFirst("RoleType").Value`

I think it's stupid as I already have a Claim with a `ClaimTypes.Role`. But that's the only easy way I can retrieve it. But perhaps there is another "easy way" that I am missing. I am a beginner...

Another question is why is there only the `Name`, `IsAuthenticated` and `AuthenticationType` properties accessible via `"@User.Identity..."`. In the end, there is a list of built-in claims you can use and add  to the `ClaimsPrincipal` and therefore you would except them to be accessible like the 3 aforementioned ones.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The [`ClaimsIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity?view=netcore-3.1) allows configuring its default claim types [`NameClaimType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.nameclaimtype?view=netcore-3.1) and [`RoleClaimType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.roleclaimtype?view=netcore-3.1) which are then used by different parts of the framework as a shortcut to work with the claim values.

One of these shortcuts is [`ClaimsIdentity.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.name?view=netcore-3.1) which just returns the value of the first claim of the identity that has a claim type of that configured default `NameClaimType`. Another shortcut is [`ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.isinrole?view=netcore-3.1) which checks whether an identity has a claim of type `RoleClaimType` with the specified value.

The idea behind those configurable claim types for names and roles is that there isn’t *one* standard claim type for each. For example, for a name you might want to use [`ClaimTypes.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes.name?view=netframework-4.8) (which value is `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"`), or [`ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes.nameidentifier?view=netframework-4.8) (which value is `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"`).

If you have a system that integrates with other non-Microsoft platforms, you might want to stick to the way simpler [JWT claim types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml) instead. There, you could use the claim type `"name"`, or `"preferred_username"`. Similarly, in some setups, the role claim type might just be `"role"`.

So basically, claim types are not really standardized and you might have to choose different types in different applications and scenarios. And that’s okay. But because there are a few utilities in the .NET types, you might have to specify which name and role claim types you are using if you want those utilities to work properly.

---

As for retrieval of claims, as you saw yourself, there aren’t just properties that you can access. Instead, there are utility methods that allow you to query for claims. The most common one is [`ClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.findfirst?view=netcore-3.1) which returns the first claim of a specific type. If you just want to check for existance, you can also use [`ClaimsPrincipal.HasClaim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.hasclaim?view=netcore-3.1).

Inside ASP.NET Core, you also have the very useful extension method [`ClaimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.principalextensions.findfirstvalue?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which will just return the claim value for a specific claim type. This is what you will probably using most of the time.

As a personal recommendation, I would also consider creating your own set of application specific extension methods on `ClaimsPrincipal` which allows you to directly retrieve the value for a claim type that is specific to your application. This will also give you the ability to directly parse the claim value into whatever type you want (since claims are only string-based). This could for example look like this:

```
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static string GetName(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
        => user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);

    public static string GetRole(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
        => user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);

    public static int GetId(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
        => int.Parse(user.FindFirstValue("id"));
}
```

Then, you can use these extension methods directly on the `User` object that exists throughout ASP.NET Core, e.g. within views or controllers:

```
<div class="user-info">
    <strong>@User.GetName() (@User.GetId())</strong>
    Current role: @User.GetRole()
</div>
```

One final note: Usually, a single identity is expected to be able to be in multiple roles at the same time. That’s why the framework does not have a single `Role` property to get the *single* role claim value, but gives you a `IsInRole` method instead to check a single role value against the set of roles the user is in. Of course, this is just the default assumption: If your application just uses a single role value, then it’s perfectly fine to treat the role claim just like any other claim where you only expect a single value.