# Why in ASP .NET Authorize tag always return 401 (Unauthorized)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm making my first API using the ASP .NET 7 framework. I am using JWT token.  I have this problem that the authorize tag always returns Unauthorize. I have checked that the correct access token comes from the client, and the only problem is that the tag can't validate it. I am attaching the structure of my project in PNG. Here is code of my Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;


using WebApi.Models;
using WebApi.Services;
using WebApi;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("UserList"));

builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPasswordHasher, PasswordHasher>();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            
            ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,
            
            ValidateAudience = true,
            
            ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
            
            ValidateLifetime = true, //make true after tests
            
            IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
            
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        };
        
        
    });

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();



app.Run();
```

Now my token generation:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;


using System.Text;


namespace WebApi.Services {
    
    public class TokenService : ITokenService {

        public string GenerateAccessToken(string username) {

            List<Claim> claims = new() {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
            };

            SymmetricSecurityKey key = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AuthOptions.SECRETKEY));
            SigningCredentials creds = new(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            
            JwtSecurityToken token = new(
                issuer: AuthOptions.ISSUER,
                audience: AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(AuthOptions.ACCESSTOKENLIFETIME),
                signingCredentials: creds
            );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            

        }
}
```

And the place in my controller where I'm trying to use [Authorize]

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserById(int id) {

    
    string username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

    string token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Replace("Bearer ", "");

    _logger.LogInformation(username + " username");
    _logger.LogInformation(token + " token");

    User? user = await _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.email == username);

    

    if (user == null) {
        return NotFound("User not found");
    }

    int userId = user.id;

    if (userId != id) {
        return Unauthorized("Unauthorized");
    }

    string newAccessToken = _tokenService.GenerateAccessToken(user.username);

    UserInfoResponse userInfo = new() {

        username = user.username,
        id = user.id,
        avatar = user.avatar,
        accessToken = newAccessToken
    };

    return Ok(userInfo);
    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JWJI.png)

I tried commenting out https enforcement (app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in Program.cs), but that didn't help

Comment: I see `IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey()` at one point and then `SymmetricSecurityKey key = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AuthOptions.SECRETKEY));`  - are you sure both lines of code are equivalent ?

Comment: You could add your own class for `JwtBearerEvents` while configuring `JwtBearerOptions` at startup. Luckily you will find methods to override, like `AuthenticationFailed` that will give you more explanation on the origin of the failure perhaps ?

Comment: Yes, these lines are equivalent, I am not sure how to make my own class, and I have not Startup file, I read that they removed it in version 6 but I dont know. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Also I don't really understand why you are returning a token on an `[Authorize]` action ? Is this for refreshing an existing token ? I usually create an access token to an API within an `[AllowAnonymous]` action

Comment: I want only authorised users to be able to access this endpoint, but I understand that now it doesn't really matter which tag is selected, they normally work with the token in the same way

Comment: I assume you are using postman to send a request to your API ? When I use it, I do not have double quote in the value, would this be the issue here ?

Comment: [You should add bearer token like this, then tell me the test result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5eBR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for access based on `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`, however you are adding the username as a claim.

Try checking for the username like this:

```
string username = context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Select(a => a.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Check also the `ClaimsPrincipalExtensions` example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63978916/1543677)

Answer (score 1):

IssuerSigningKey in program.cs and SymmetricSecurityKey in TokenService must be the same. You need to change addAuthentication in Program.cs to:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        
        ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,
        
        ValidateAudience = true,
        
        ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
        
        ValidateLifetime = true, //make true after tests
        
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AuthOptions.SECRETKEY)), // it must be the same with SymmetricSecurityKey in TokenService 
        
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    };
    
    
});
```